# Git: how to pull in someone elses work within the same repo?

Tags: git, github

I have a co-worker that has changed a file within a repo we've both been working on.

I'd like to pull their changes on to my local. I am not sure how to do this. From the same repo, I've tried:

```
git checkout their-branch-name
git pull their-branch-name
git fetch their-branch-name
```

But all these result in

> fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

How do I pull a particular from this repository? How do I even find out the depositories name on Github?

Comment: This error can occur due to multiple reasons. To list the remotes, use `git remote -v`. To start with see if this remote exists.

Answer (score 1):

If your coworkers work has been pushed into its own branch that you haven't checked out yet, you can use `git checkout --track origin/branch-name` to download the branch onto your own machine.

If you haven't downloaded their repo at all yet, you'll need to use `git clone repo-url` to get the repo the first time. On github you can click the green 'clone or download' button on a repo's page to get the url.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure a `remote`. You normally do this when cloning a repository from another `upstream` location.

See https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes for more info.